# Skype on HP ENVY m6 Sleekbook has no sound

Tags: sound, skype

There is no sound with Skype on my new HP ENVY m6 Sleekbook.
I tried all permutations and options offered. No luck.
This makes Skype unusable with UBUNTU and UBUNTU not as attractive to use as it should be.
Any suggestions?
Michael.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [this page on sorting out Skype audio problems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SkypeTroubleshooting#Selecting_Microphone_.28input_device.29)?

Answer (score 0):

Well for international calls you can try [Viber](http://www.viber.com/products/linux) as well.